# Menu toggle - Page is loading with menu expanded

Tags: toggle

I am having difficulty with my menu on my website www.callumritchie.com

When I load the website the menu at the top of the page is already expanded and then when you click the menu icon it hides it.

I want the menu to be hidden when the page is loaded, requiring the visitor to click the menu icon to reveal/expand the menu.

HTML
    
    
        
    
    
        Home
        Work
        Contact
        About

jquery

```
$("#menuicon").click(function () {
$("#sitemenu").show("fast");
});
```

CSS

```
#switch {
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
background-color: #6ea9ca;
border-left: 15px solid #6ea9ca;
border-top: 15px solid #6ea9ca;
border-bottom: 15px solid #6ea9ca;
}
#switch img {
transition: transform .25s linear;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .25s linear;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform .25s linear;
}
#menu nav {
font-family:'DroidSans';
margin-top: 23px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 36px;
z-index: 1;
transition: all .25s linear;
-moz-transition: all .25s linear;
-webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
-o-transition: all .25s linear;
}
#menu.active nav {
left: -20em;
opacity: 0;
 }
#menu.active #switch img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    `$(document).ready(function(){$("#sitemenu").hide()});`

edit in response: just swap out `#sitemenu` for the id of the element you want hidden.

Comment: hmm, I can't actually remember how I made this - the '#sitemenu' doesn't seem to appear anywhere else so i'm not sure if it is needed